# Banking Advice for my new Job

Tags: india, banking, bank-account, working-abroad

I am moving to UAE for my new job soon from India. This is my first job as well. My Employer asked me to send my Banking Details. So what kind of account should I start, where should I start, and what tips can I have for maximum benefit from that account?

What are the basic banking details I should work out before I move?

Answer (score 1):

> My Employer asked me to send my Banking Details.

Why does your employer need your bank account details without you joining yet? Please verify and be sure that this is not some kind of scam.

> What are the basic banking details I should work out before I move?

Convert any savings account into NRO. Open an NRE account.

Comment: No.. It is not a scam. I have verified.. And they want my bank details for setting up my payroll

Answer (score -1):

Most banks have a procedure that you fill out a form on line and the bank gathers all the info need for direct deposit. To start you off you need a basic checking account. I wouldn't give any info to your employer but rather start the direct deposit with you bank first, its safer.